# Keeping rows with different values in another column in R

Tags: r

I have something similar to the following:

`df<-data.frame(one=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7), two=c(1010,1010,1011,1011,1011, 1012, 1012, 1013, 1013))`

I'd like to keep the rows where the value in 'two' has different values in 'one' (i.e. exclude two==1013, and two==1010). I was able to do this with setDT and uniqueN but I'm looking for another way to validate. I'm sure there's an easy way just can't find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `group_by` 'two' and create a logical condition on 'one' with `n_distinct` i.e. number of distinct elements to be greater than 1

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(two) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(one)  > 1)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   two [2]
#    one   two
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2  1011
#2     3  1011
#3     4  1011
#4     5  1012
#5     6  1012
```

---

Or in `base R` with `duplicated`

```
df[!(duplicated(df)|duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE)),]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(one) %>%
    filter(!anyDuplicated(two))
```

Comment: There is `anyDuplicated` function